# Referencing other grails projects

Tags: grails, groovy, ggts

I am trying to use domain classes of one grails project in other grails projects. I am using GGTS as IDE.
I imported grails project containing domain classes and added it to the build path of my second project.
When I try to reference any of domain classes in second project I get no errors in GGTS but when I run app i get:
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
unable to resolve class domainClass

Answer (score 2):

A better solution is to create a Grails plugin, add the domain classses to the plugin (and anything else that should be shared by the 2 applications), and install the plugin in the 2 applications.

Answer (score 0):

that is definite that you should create the other project as plugin.

Please , consult this [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html) and let me know any thing ,if u want help.